# Retreive the underlying column name for an alias

Tags: mysql, sql, subquery

Let's say I have the query below.

```
SELECT UserSub.Lastname 
FROM (
    SELECT UserId, Email, Firstname, Lastname as COL_1234 
    FROM Users
) 
as UsersSub;
```

This will result in an error

```
Error Code: 1054. Unknown column 'UsersSub.Lastname' in 'field list'
```

I know it doesn't work because the column `Lastname` is not returned by the subquery. When I change `UsersSub.Lastname` to `UsersSub.COL_1234` it works flawlessly. But I need a way to retreive the original column name based on the alias. The subquery is being generated by another part of the code that I can't change, so that's something I have no influence on. Because later on I need to add a where clause to the query and I need to search on the aliased fields. So in the coming feature the query will look like below.

```
SELECT UserSub.Lastname 
FROM (
    SELECT UserId, Email, Firstname, Lastname as COL_1234 
    FROM Users
) 
as UsersSub
WHERE UserSub.Lastname LIKE '%son';
```

Comment: Why don' call twice? `LastName` and `COL_1234`?

Comment: @dwir182 I don't get it, do you have an example?

Comment: You want to aliasing the `LastName`? But you need to retrieve with the original column name for aggregate function?

Comment: Ahh i get it.. Your machine generate this `subquery` but you can't use them for aggregate because the aliasing name always changing.. Is that your problem?

Comment: You can't put condition if you don't know your column you are using..

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think this will work:

```
SELECT u.Lastname
FROM (
    SELECT UserId, Email, Firstname, Lastname as COL_1234 
    FROM Users
) AS UsersSub
LEFT JOIN ON Users AS u WHERE UsersSub.UserId = u.UserId
WHERE UserSub.Lastname LIKE '%son';
```

Answer (score 0):

try this, its working fine for me

```
SELECT UserSub.Lastname 
FROM (
    SELECT UserId, Email, Firstname, Lastname, Lastname as COL_1234 
    FROM Users
) 
as UsersSub
WHERE UserSub.Lastname LIKE '%son';
```

Comment: I can't change the subquery.